# Install yum-cron? Or run yum makecache fast error AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

Went to run **sudo yum update -y**

Got this error:

```
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
```

Ran **yum clean all**

Still getting same error after running yum clean all. This on AWS EC2 service. I don't know what else to do. Can't seem to find a solution on google.

Comment: i am also getting this error on ec2 .. can someone help???